# Compressing a blob in javascript

Tags: javascript, compression, blob

I need to send a blob to the server with ajax, but it can end up getting somewhat large, and I'd like to decrease upload time. I've tried jszip already, but that just gave me an empty file inside the zip. I've also tried btoa(), but it turns out that the encoded value just ends up being [object Blob] instead of the actual blob data. What are my options for compressing blobs?

Here was the code I used for jszip:

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("recording.wav", blobFile);
var content = zip.generate();
```

I then appended "content" to a FormData object and sent it to the server. On the server side, I decoded the POST data (from base64). The zip file opened just fine, but recording.wav was a 0 length file.

Additionally, I've tried using the LZW implementation found [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#JavaScript). This was the additional code I used to compress it:

```
var compressed;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event){
   compressed = LZW.compress(event.target.result);
};
reader.readAsText(blobFile);
```

However, decompressing it returns null.

Comment: How did you try to use jszip? I don't think [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.btoa) is what you want to use if size a problem, that produces Base64 data and that makes things bigger.

Comment: Question edited to show how jszip was used.

Comment: It's a Blob object with an undefined type.

Comment: Can you pull the bytes out of the Blob as a String and then hand that to jszip?

Comment: I tried that, with FileReader's readAsBinaryString() function, but the zip ended up being bigger than the resulting file is without zipping. Also, the resulting recording.wav was not a valid audio file.

Comment: Have you tried to zip a `.wav` file by hand to see if compression is even worth the effort? A lot of file formats are compressed internally so zipping them is no use; this is pretty common with audio, video, and other "naturally large" formats.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't seem to make it smaller when I manually add it to a zip, but I still need some way of compressing the data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Caveat: compressing things like audio files would be better done using an algorithm meant specifically for that type of data, perhaps something lossy.  However, knowing how hard it was to find a reasonable lossless implementation as provided below, I'm very concerned that it will be hard to find a good implementation in Javascript for that type of data specifically that meets your needs.

In any case, I've had this general need for compression/decompression in Javascript as well, and I needed the same algorithm to work both client (browser) and server-side (node.js) and I needed it to work on very large files.  I had checked out jszip and I also tried that LZW algorithm among at least five or six others none of which satisfied the requirements.  I can't remember what the issue was with each specifically, but suffice to say it is surprisingly hard to find a good and FAST compressor/decompressor in javascript that works both server and client side and handles large files!  I tried at least a dozen different implementations of various compression algorithms, and finally settled with this one - it hasn't failed me yet!

---

**UPDATE**

This is the original source:
https://code.google.com/p/jslzjb/source/browse/trunk/Iuppiter.js?r=2

By someone named Bear - thanks Bear, whoever you are, you're the best.
It is LZJB: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZJB

---

**UPDATE 2**

1. Corrected a problem with missing semicolon - should not give the object not a function error any longer.
2. This implementation stops working on data less than about 80 characters in length. So I updated the example to reflect that.
3. Realized the base64 encode/decode methods are in fact exposed on the object passed in for this version, so...
4. Currently seeing what we can do about specific blob types - what for example the best approach would be for a image versus audio etc as that would be useful for JS folks in general... will update here with what is found.

---

**UPDATE 3**

There is a much better wrapper around the original Iuppiter source from Bear than the one I posted below.  It is written by cscott and on github here:  https://github.com/cscott/lzjb

I'll be switching to this one, as it does streams as well.

Below is an example in Node.js of its use with a wav file.  But before copying the example, let me give you the terrible news first, at least for this one wav file that I tried:

```
63128 Jun 19 14:09 beep-1.wav 
63128 Jun 19 17:47 beep-2.wav
89997 Jun 19 17:47 beep-2.wav.compressed
```

So it successfully regenerated the wav (and it played).  However, the compressed one appears to be larger than the original.  Well shoot.  In any case, might be good to try on your data, you never know, you might get lucky.  Here's the code I used:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var lzjb = require('lzjb');

fs.readFile('beep-1.wav', function(err, wav){

    // base 64 first
    var encoded = wav.toString('base64');
    // then utf8 - you  don't want to go utf-8 directly
    var data = new Buffer(encoded, 'utf8');
    // now compress
    var compressed = lzjb.compressFile(data, null, 9);
    // the next two lines are unnecessary, but to see what kind of
    // size is written to disk  to compare with the original binary file
    var compressedBuffer = new Buffer(compressed, 'binary');
    fs.writeFile('beep-2.wav.compressed', compressedBuffer, 'binary', function(err) {});
    // decompress
    var uncompressed = lzjb.decompressFile(compressed);
    // decode from utf8 back to base64
    var encoded2 = new Buffer(uncompressed).toString('utf8');
    // decode back to binary original from base64
    var decoded = new Buffer(encoded2, 'base64');
    // write it out, make sure it is identical
    fs.writeFile('beep-2.wav', decoded, function(err) {});

});
```

At the end of the day, I think its going to be too difficult to achieve any level of compression on most forms of binary data that isn't clobbered by the resulting base64 encoding.  The days of control characters for terminals still haunt us to this day.  You could try upping to a different base, but that has its risks and issues as well.

See this for example:
[What is the most efficient binary to text encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971211/what-is-the-most-efficient-binary-to-text-encoding/4441606#4441606)

And this:
[Why don't people use base128?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008047/why-dont-people-use-base128-in-javascript/6009172#6009172)

---

One thing though, definitely before you accept the answer, please please try it out on your blob, I've mainly used it for compressing utf-8, and I'd like to be sure it works on your specific data.

In any case, here it is!

```
/**
$Id: Iuppiter.js 3026 2010-06-23 10:03:13Z Bear $

Copyright (c) 2010 Nuwa Information Co., Ltd, and individual contributors.
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

  1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

  2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

  3. Neither the name of Nuwa Information nor the names of its contributors
     may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
     without specific prior written permission.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

$Author: Bear $
$Date: 2010-06-23 18:03:13 +0800 (星期三, 23 六月 2010) $
$Revision: 3026 $
*/
var fastcompressor = {};
(function (k) {
    k.toByteArray = function (c) {
        var h = [],
            b, a;
        for (b = 0; b < c.length; b++) a = c.charCodeAt(b), 127 >= a ? h.push(a) : (2047 >= a ? h.push(a >> 6 | 192) : (65535 >= a ? h.push(a >> 12 | 224) : (h.push(a >> 18 | 240), h.push(a >> 12 & 63 | 128)), h.push(a >> 6 & 63 | 128)), h.push(a & 63 | 128));
        return h
    };
    k.Base64 = {
        CA: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",
        CAS: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_",
        IA: Array(256),
        IAS: Array(256),
        init: function () {
            var c;
            for (c = 0; 256 > c; c++) k.Base64.IA[c] = -1, k.Base64.IAS[c] = -1;
            c = 0;
            for (iS = k.Base64.CA.length; c < iS; c++) k.Base64.IA[k.Base64.CA.charCodeAt(c)] = c, k.Base64.IAS[k.Base64.CAS.charCodeAt(c)] = c;
            k.Base64.IA["="] = k.Base64.IAS["="] = 0
        },
        encode: function (c, h) {
            var b, a, d, e, m, g, f, l, j;
            b = h ? k.Base64.CAS : k.Base64.CA;
            d = c.constructor == Array ? c : k.toByteArray(c);
            e = d.length;
            m = 3 * (e / 3);
            g = (e - 1) / 3 + 1 << 2;
            a = Array(g);
            for (l = f = 0; f < m;) j = (d[f++] & 255) << 16 | (d[f++] & 255) << 8 | d[f++] & 255, a[l++] = b.charAt(j >> 18 & 63), a[l++] = b.charAt(j >> 12 & 63), a[l++] = b.charAt(j >> 6 & 63), a[l++] = b.charAt(j & 63);
            f = e - m;
            0 < f && (j = (d[m] &
                255) << 10 | (2 == f ? (d[e - 1] & 255) << 2 : 0), a[g - 4] = b.charAt(j >> 12), a[g - 3] = b.charAt(j >> 6 & 63), a[g - 2] = 2 == f ? b.charAt(j & 63) : "=", a[g - 1] = "=");
            return a.join("")
        },
        decode: function (c, h) {
            var b, a, d, e, m, g, f, l, j, p, q, n;
            b = h ? k.Base64.IAS : k.Base64.IA;
            c.constructor == Array ? (d = c, m = !0) : (d = k.toByteArray(c), m = !1);
            e = d.length;
            g = 0;
            for (f = e - 1; g < f && 0 > b[d[g]];) g++;
            for (; 0 < f && 0 > b[d[f]];) f--;
            l = "=" == d[f] ? "=" == d[f - 1] ? 2 : 1 : 0;
            a = f - g + 1;
            j = 76 < e ? ("\r" == d[76] ? a / 78 : 0) << 1 : 0;
            e = (6 * (a - j) >> 3) - l;
            a = Array(e);
            q = p = 0;
            for (eLen = 3 * (e / 3); p < eLen;) n = b[d[g++]] << 18 | b[d[g++]] <<
                12 | b[d[g++]] << 6 | b[d[g++]], a[p++] = n >> 16 & 255, a[p++] = n >> 8 & 255, a[p++] = n & 255, 0 < j && 19 == ++q && (g += 2, q = 0);
            if (p < e) {
                for (j = n = 0; g <= f - l; j++) n |= b[d[g++]] << 18 - 6 * j;
                for (b = 16; p < e; b -= 8) a[p++] = n >> b & 255
            }
            if (m) return a;
            for (n = 0; n < a.length; n++) a[n] = String.fromCharCode(a[n]);
            return a.join("")
        }
    };
    k.Base64.init();
    NBBY = 8;
    MATCH_BITS = 6;
    MATCH_MIN = 3;
    MATCH_MAX = (1 << MATCH_BITS) + (MATCH_MIN - 1);
    OFFSET_MASK = (1 << 16 - MATCH_BITS) - 1;
    LEMPEL_SIZE = 256;
    k.compress = function (c) {
        var h = [],
            b, a = 0,
            d = 0,
            e, m, g = 1 << NBBY - 1,
            f, l, j = Array(LEMPEL_SIZE);
        for (b = 0; b < LEMPEL_SIZE; b++) j[b] =
            3435973836;
        c = c.constructor == Array ? c : k.toByteArray(c);
        for (b = c.length; a < b;) {
            if ((g <<= 1) == 1 << NBBY) {
                if (d >= b - 1 - 2 * NBBY) {
                    f = b;
                    for (d = a = 0; f; f--) h[d++] = c[a++];
                    break
                }
                g = 1;
                m = d;
                h[d++] = 0
            }
            if (a > b - MATCH_MAX) h[d++] = c[a++];
            else if (e = (c[a] + 13 ^ c[a + 1] - 13 ^ c[a + 2]) & LEMPEL_SIZE - 1, l = a - j[e] & OFFSET_MASK, j[e] = a, e = a - l, 0 <= e && e != a && c[a] == c[e] && c[a + 1] == c[e + 1] && c[a + 2] == c[e + 2]) {
                h[m] |= g;
                for (f = MATCH_MIN; f < MATCH_MAX && c[a + f] == c[e + f]; f++);
                h[d++] = f - MATCH_MIN << NBBY - MATCH_BITS | l >> NBBY;
                h[d++] = l;
                a += f
            } else h[d++] = c[a++]
        }
        return h
    };
    k.decompress = function (c,
        h) {
        var b, a = [],
            d, e = 0,
            m = 0,
            g, f, l = 1 << NBBY - 1,
            j;
        b = c.constructor == Array ? c : k.toByteArray(c);
        for (d = b.length; e < d;) {
            if ((l <<= 1) == 1 << NBBY) l = 1, f = b[e++];
            if (f & l)
                if (j = (b[e] >> NBBY - MATCH_BITS) + MATCH_MIN, g = (b[e] << NBBY | b[e + 1]) & OFFSET_MASK, e += 2, 0 <= (g = m - g))
                    for (; 0 <= --j;) a[m++] = a[g++];
                else break;
                else a[m++] = b[e++]
        }
        if (!("undefined" == typeof h ? 0 : h)) {
            for (b = 0; b < m; b++) a[b] = String.fromCharCode(a[b]);
            a = a.join("")
        }
        return a
    }
})(fastcompressor);
```

And if memory serves... here's how you use it:

```
var compressed = fastcompressor.compress("0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"); // data less than this length poses issues.
var decompressed = fastcompressor.decompress(compressed);
```

Rgds....Hoonto/Matt

Also, what I've posted is minified but beautified, and very slightly adapted for ease-of-use. Check the link in the update above for the original stuff.

Comment: I'm working with this now. It looks promising, but I won't know until I'm done.

Comment: Great, I hope it works out, keep in mind LZJB may not always provide the best compression, but it is very fast (originally used in Sun Microsystems ZFS).  Also, there are base64 encode/decode methods in both the version posted here and the Iupiter one.  I didn't expose them on the argument object though.  Also, as I'm sure you know, base64 encoding can add quite a bit of size,  so compression post-encoding may not be much sometimes.  What we really need are a few good lossy ones with the same speed and flexibility as this one to round out a compress/decompress library for JS.

Comment: I wasn't able to use the code you pasted (object is not a function error), but I did use the code from the site you linked. The problem is, it doesn't take a blob. Using a blob as an argument in Iuppiter.compress() returns an empty array. How did you pass a blob?

Comment: Ah yes - that's where you need to base64 encode and you may, depending on the type of data that your blob is, you may lose quite a bit of compression efficiency there - which if that is the case you may need to continue the search for a compression algorithm that is better suited to that type of data, but the problem is Javascript as it is in the browser is a pretty poor language for doing compression algorithms for a variety of reasons which is probably why we see a lack of those kinds of implementations.  Try base64 encoding the data, then pass as string to the encode function.

Comment: I'll see what's wrong with that version I posted in about 20 minutes, I apologize in advance, I must have a typo in there!!  Will fix momentarily.

Comment: Ok that's fixed - it was a typo on my part.

Comment: I should have just taken your word for it, but I had to try it myself and came to your conclusion - by the time it hits a blob, it's not getting any further compressed. That leaves compressing the data before creating the blob. For that, I'm using a Uint8Array. You wouldn't happen to have any ideas for that, would you?

Comment: If the blob is created on a system in which you have the ability to install software, the server, or if this is a system to live in the corporate intranet, and you can ask employees to install something you could use specific encoders to data type outside of the browser.  For example for WAV there is: http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=LossyWAV

Comment: However that usually isn't an option and I'm not aware of anything like LossyWAV written in browser-side Javascript.  There are some Node libraries that do audio stuff that could be a starting point for writing such a component.  Interesting but certainly not a trival project from what it looks like.  At npmjs.org, there are these audio libraries that might get you started if that's a course of action that sounds reasonable: https://npmjs.org/search?q=audio and this one: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-wav

Comment: I'll leave the bounty open for now, since I still have time, but this is, in all likelihood, the correct answer. Not the answer I wanted, perhaps, but the correct one.

Comment: There is one last option possibly, if you know the type of data, say wav for example, and there is available a native implementation of a compressor that is efficient enough to overcome the base64 encoding bloat (like LossyWAV for example), that can be compiled with llvm (http://llvm.org/), then you may be able to use emscripten (https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) to perform the port to Javascript.  Some amazing successes in that category include the port of the Qt library and llvm itself to Javascript.  So that might be an option.

Comment: @hoonto Is there a way to compress to a base64 String of image dataUrl?

Answer (score 1):

JS Zip will work fine just correct your syntax..

```
function create_zip() {
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.add("recording.wav", blobfile);//here you have to give blobFile in the form of raw bits >> convert it in json notation.. or stream .. 
    zip.add("hello2.txt", "Hello Second World\n");//this is optional..
    content = zip.generate();
    location.href="data:application/zip;base64," + content;
}
```

you can add multiple files too..

Just zip.file will become zip.add

and then zip.generate() will do the rest.. as you have done,

or refer [old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690395/passing-sound-wav-file-to-javascript-from-objective-c) its last part of JavaScript, and NativeBridge will be helpful if you can utilize, in this post user records using Objective C that you can ignore, but sends this object using JavaScript and Socket that you can/may utilize..

I hope this will do ... :)

Comment: Hi @MarmiK, can you please be more specific and give any examples with the blogfile you are mentioning.

Comment: Please let me know which section you want clarification on, I have answered in sort to help the question, JS zip is a library(just for clarification, I am sure you know it!), using that library things becomes easy to zip on the go..

Comment: Thank you, @MarkmiK. Already solved my problem by looking into the jsziputils and a binary: true option for the data.