# How to add multiple files to a zip with zip.js?

Tags: zip, javascript

I am using the javascript [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) library. I've seach all around I a cannot find an example where more than one file is added to the zip.

Here is my code, but it generates a "corrupted" zip.

```
var len = results.rows.length, i;
var k=1;
zip.createWriter(new zip.BlobWriter(), function(writer) {
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        // get the image url from a sqlite request
        url = results.rows.item(i).url;


        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = this.src;
            var filename= a.pathname.split('/').pop(); // filename.php
            timest = new Date().getTime();
            // use a TextReader to read the String to add

                writer.add(timest+".jpg", new zip.Data64URIReader(getBase64Image(img)), function() {
                // onsuccess callback
                    k++;
                    if(k==len){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        writer.close(function(blob) {

                            // blob contains the zip file as a Blob object
                            $('#test').attr("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                            $('#test').attr("download", "woeii.zip");

                        });
                        },1000);
                    }
                }, function(currentIndex, totalIndex) {
                // onprogress callback
                });



        };
        img.src = url;
    }
});
```

Any idea to make it work? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for a good example of code that handles multiple files, [see here](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo1.html). You can then [view the source code](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo1.js).

This is the key source of the demo (modified just slightly):

```
var obj = this;
var model = (function() {
    var zipFileEntry, zipWriter, writer, creationMethod, URL = obj.webkitURL || obj.mozURL || obj.URL;

    return {
        setCreationMethod : function(method) {
            creationMethod = method;
        },
        addFiles : function addFiles(files, oninit, onadd, onprogress, onend) {
            var addIndex = 0;

            function nextFile() {
                var file = files[addIndex];
                onadd(file);
                // Modified here to use the Data64URIReader instead of BlobReader
                zipWriter.add(file.name, new zip.Data64URIReader(file.data), function() {
                    addIndex++;
                    if (addIndex < files.length)
                        nextFile();
                    else
                        onend();
                }, onprogress);
            }

            function createZipWriter() {
                zip.createWriter(writer, function(writer) {
                    zipWriter = writer;
                    oninit();
                    nextFile();
                }, onerror);
            }

            if (zipWriter)
                nextFile();
            else if (creationMethod == "Blob") {
                writer = new zip.BlobWriter();
                createZipWriter();
            } else {
                createTempFile(function(fileEntry) {
                    zipFileEntry = fileEntry;
                    writer = new zip.FileWriter(zipFileEntry);
                    createZipWriter();
                });
            }
        },
        getBlobURL : function(callback) {
            zipWriter.close(function(blob) {
                var blobURL = creationMethod == "Blob" ? URL.createObjectURL(blob) : zipFileEntry.toURL();
                callback(blobURL);
                zipWriter = null;
            });
        },
        getBlob : function(callback) {
            zipWriter.close(callback);
        }
    };
})();
```

Usage:
Assumes a `<a id="downloadLink">Download</a>` element exists to provide the download once ready.

```
// Prepare your images
var files = [];
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    // Get the image URL from a SQLite request
    var url = results.rows.item(i).url;

    (function(url){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            // Add to file array [{name, data}]
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = this.src;
            var filename= a.pathname.split('/').pop();

            console.log("Loaded file " + filename);
            files.push({name: filename, data: getBase64Image(img) });
        }
        img.src = url;
    })(url);
}

// Wait for the image to load
var check = setInterval(function(){
    if(files.length==images.length) {
        clearInterval(check);

        // Set the mode
        model.setCreationMethod("Blob");

        // Add the files to the zip
        model.addFiles(files, 
            function() {
                // Initialise Method
                console.log("Initialise");
            }, function(file) {
                // OnAdd
                console.log("Added file");
            }, function(current, total) {
                // OnProgress
                console.log("%s %s", current, total);
            }, function() {
                // OnEnd
                // The zip is ready prepare download link
                // <a id="downloadLink" href="blob:url">Download Zip</a>
                model.getBlobURL(function(url) {
                    document.getElementById("downloadLink").href = url;
                    document.getElementById("downloadLink").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("downloadLink").download = "filename.zip";
                });
            });

    }
}, 500);
```

You can use the example source code to add in progress indicators.
Hope this helps, the nice thing about this method is the zip model is easily reusable if you make it it's own JS file.

---

Another thought: I presume you are using the `getBase64Image` function [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript), if so and you still experience corruption issues, perhaps try modifying the return to simply `return dataURL;` and comment out the `.replace(...`, as the `Data64URIReader` may expect the prefix.

Comment: Thx ! :) this seems to work. I have one last issue, only the last image is saved several times in the zip. I think it comes from the model function. I am looking into it.

Comment: I made a change to the code a few minutes ago you may have not got. In the image loader make sure there is `var` infront of URL or the `onload` function won't pick up the variable properly.

Comment: the problem was indeed on the url var. Thought because of the asynchronous execution of the `onload` function, it still saved the last image several times. 

I solved it using an anonymous function around the `img.onload`

Once again thank you :) If you didn't help me I would have been stuck for days!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a stripped-down version of [that demo](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo1.html) that only uses RAM storage. It assumes that zip.js, z-worker.js, and deflate.js from the zip.js install are in the same directory as the two files below, along with [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

*Note:* This is not production-ready code! It is a bare-bones demo that I made so I could figure out what was going on. If you generate and save the zip programmatically, you may need to implement a nextFile() iterator like the one above to prevent a race condition from populating the zip with empty files. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29738675/738675 for an example of this.)

**demo.html:**

```
<li>
    add files into the zip
    <input type="file" multiple id="file-input" onchange="addFiles(this.files)">
</li>
<li>
    download the zip file
    <a href="#" onclick="saveZip()">Download</a>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript" src="zip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FileSaver.js"></script>
```

**demo.js:**

```
var zipWriter;

function addFiles(files) {
    writer = new zip.BlobWriter();
    zip.createWriter(writer, function(writer) {
        zipWriter = writer;
        for (var f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {
            zipWriter.add(files[f].name,
            new zip.BlobReader(files[f]), function() {});
        }
    });
}

function saveZip() {
    zipWriter.close(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, "Example.zip"); // uses FileSaver.js
        document.getElementById("file-input").value = null; // reset input file list
        zipWriter = null;
    });
}
```