# How to handle multiple images to download using Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, download, jszip, filesaver.js

I have a route called /photos, which supports pagination through a 'page' query parameter and allows me to specify the number of photos per page using 'pageSize'. It returns an array of photos and the total count of photos available.

```
This is my api route
/photos?cameraId=580&start=2023-10-29&end=2023-10-30&beginTime=18:00&endTime=19:00&Page=1&PageSize=10
```

```json
This is my return object
{
    "photos": [
        {  "urlPreview": "https://example.com/random-preview-url"  }
        ...
    ],
    "total": 239
}
```

Now, I need to implement a button on my page that, when clicked, will start downloading these photos. The total number of photos is approximately 12K, which obviously takes some time and processing.

I've been advised to use localStorage to save the photos incrementally and then zip them all for the user to download.

However, I have no idea how to implement this as I've never done anything like this before. Can someone please guide me on how to proceed?

I was trying to download using my downloadMassivePhotos function like this

```
import JSZip from 'jszip';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

export const downloadMassivePhotos = async (
  cameraId,
  start,
  end,
  beginTime,
  endTime,
) => {
  const zip = new JSZip();
  const maxConcurrentDownloads = 20;
  let activeDownloads = 0;

  try {
    const { photos } = await fetchAPI({
      path: 'photos',
      query: { cameraId, start, end, beginTime, endTime },
    });

    for (const photo of photos) {
      while (activeDownloads >= maxConcurrentDownloads) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      }

      activeDownloads++;

      fetchAndZipPhoto(photo, zip)
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(`Error downloading photo ${photo.id}:`, error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          activeDownloads--;
        });
    }

    while (activeDownloads > 0) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }

    const content = await zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' });
    saveAs(content, 'photos.zip');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const fetchAndZipPhoto = async (photo, zip) => {
  const { urlImage, id } = photo;
  const response = await fetch(urlImage);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
  }
  const blob = await response.blob();
  zip.file(`${id}.jpg`, blob, { binary: true });
};
```

And this is my fetch method

```js
export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST,
});

export const fetchAPI = async <T>({ path, query, context }: FetchAPI) => {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  const { data, status } = await api.get<T>(`/${path}`, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.token}` },
    params: query,
  });

  if (!data && status !== 200) {
    throw new Error(`API call to ${path} failed.`);
  }

  return data;
};
```

Comment: this would mean fetching a binary stream and saving an integer array or base64-encoded bytes to a variable in the active session storage. This lets you transmit data server to client, accumulate raw data as file-handles, write to a zip file handle (also mapped to session storage), and then "download" that file handle to your actual client storage. Session storage on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage and here's a SO question about using zip.js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510979/how-to-add-multiple-files-to-a-zip-with-zip-js.